# fork on github, then how do I manage my contributions?

Tags: git, github, git-branch

I'm a little unclear on the forkflow that is to follow a `fork` on github.

What if I have several small independent fixes of various bugs in the original repository, of a medium-sized project, say, OpenGrok?

- Do I create separate branches for each relatively small unrelated bugfix?
- Do I create each branch from `master`, or could I branch one unrelated branch from the next?
- Do I commit the fixes into `master`?

I mean, over time, I still want to preserve the history and all, but I'm just afraid that after a while there'll be a complete mess in regards to a lot of meaningless branches for relatively minor bug fixes.

I plan to contribute a number of non-related fixes for a given project, and trying to do some planning of the development approach.

Answer (score 4):

There are several possible workflows when forking a project on github and you plan to submit changes upstream. This is one of the workflows I usually tend to follow (I'm going to call the repo from which I've forked as the remote `source` and my repo as `origin`):

- Fork the main branch used by `source`, let's say `master` into `origin/my-dev`.
- `origin/mydev` is where all my changes and main development go.
- I regularly rebase `remote/master` onto `origin/master` (this step is redundant but sometimes it is easy for me to have everything in one remote).
- Merge either `source/master` or the rebased `origin/master` into `origin/my-dev` whenever you want to pick up changes from upstream.
- If I would like to submit a patch or a bugfix upstream, I would start a new feature branch that I could use for the pull-request. I'll call it `origin/my-feature-1`. I create this branch off an upto date `origin/master` (or `source/master`)
- I cherry-pick the changes for this feature that I've made in `origin/my-dev` into `origin/my-feature-1`. Perform any testing after this step.
- Submit a pull request from `origin/my-feature-1`
- If your pull-request gets approved, the changes would be merged into `source/master` (and `origin/master` too).
- Perform a merge from  `origin/master` (or `source/master`) into `origin/my-dev`.
- As far as the lifetime of the branches go, I usually tend to get rid of the short-lived topic or feature branches after I've merged it upstream (Branches are just lightweight pointers in git referencing certain commit).

Keep repeating this workflow over and over.

The key idea is that your pull-request should not pose any serious conflicts for the upstream maintainer or he/she is going to blindly reject the contribution.

An example I've illustrated, when you want to contribute `D2` and `D3` from `origin/my-dev` upstream. `D2'` and `D3'` are rebased versions of `D2` and `D3`. Commits with `U` are upstream commits in `source`, `D` are your downstream commits in `origin`. The ones with the `M` suffix are merges.

Visually this is what it would look like:

```
source/master             origin/my-dev
     U1
     U2   Initial-fork
     U3-----------\
     |             \
     |              \------------D1
     |                           D2
     U4 Sync up from upstream    |
     U5-----------\              D3
     |             \             |
     U6             \------------DM4                        origin/feature-1
     |                           |
     |                           |     Starting point of feature-1
     U7------------------------------------------------------------D2'  (Rebased version of D2)
     |                           |                                 D3'  (Rebased version of D3)
     |                           D5                                /
     U8                          D6      Pull-request             /
     |                           |       getting merged upstream /
     UM9--------------------------------------------------------/
     |                           |
     |              Resync       |
     |-------------\ my-dev      |
     U9             \            |
     U10             \-----------DM7
     |                           |
     |                           |
```

Comment: I'm still a bit unclear of what is the long-term approach here: do you keep these feature-branches?  Also, how would I even name them, if they're just bugfix branches, not really any feature?  Also, when you do a rebase of your own main branch, how do you keep the history / ensure you can go back at any point in the future?  (I'm asking, because with rebase and fast-forward, the commit sha1 will change etc.)

Comment: @cnst - It does not matter if it is a feature or a bugfix, the same workflow can be applied irrespective of that. It is better to name your branches indicative of the bug you're trying to fix such as: `fix-deadlock`, `fix-397` (if you're fixing the bug number 397). If you're asking about `origin/master`, you would have noticed that I do not commit anything directly on `origin/master`, and all my merges or rebases from `remote/master` are fast-forward ones, hence I mentioned that it is redundant. BTW Fast-forward merge does not change any commit's SHA1. All my commits go in `origin/my-dev` only

Comment: So you don't really need `origin/master`, right? you could always create feature(contribution) branch from `source(remote)/master`.